# Fazer a troca de uma imageView com Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, mobile, kotlin

Olá sou nova aprendendo Kotlin e tenho o seguinte problema, tenho uma imageView com dois botões, avançar e retroceder. Em uma galeria de 5 fotos eu gostaria de ficar trocando de imagem de forma que um botão avance uma imagem e o outro retroceda. Alguém pode ajudar?

Esse é o meu código na MainActivity

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var img01: ImageView
    val imgs = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.p0,
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p3,
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p5,
        R.drawable.p6,
    )
    val x = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        img01 = findViewById(R.id.img01)
    }
    fun anterior(view: View) {

        }
    fun proximo(view: View) {




    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que:

- x é seu contador
- você tem um Button com ID `avancar` e outro `retroceder`

Você pode fazer com que o `x` seja incrementado no método `proximo()` e decrementado no método `anterior()`, seguido pela atribuição do resource correspondente da sua lista `imgs[]` pelo índice `x`.

E pra fazer com que o clique no botão chame seu método, você precisa passar um onClickListener, usando `setOnClickListener` nos botões, dessa forma:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var img01: ImageView
    lateinit var btnAvancar: Button
    lateinit var btnRetroceder: Button
    val imgs = intArrayOf( 
        R.drawable.p0,
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p3,
        R.drawable.p4,
        R.drawable.p5,
        R.drawable.p6,
    )
    var x = 0 //alterando de val pra var pra poder incrementar
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        img01 = findViewById(R.id.img01)
        btnAvancar = findViewById(R.id.avancar)
        btnRetroceder = findViewById(R.id.retroceder)

        // especificando o comportamento no clique dos botões
        btnAvancar.setOnClickListener {
            anterior(it)
        }

        btnRetroceder.setOnClickListener {
            proximo(it)
        }
    }
    fun anterior(view: View) {
        if (x > 0) {
            x -= 1
            img01.setImageResource(imgs[x])
        }
    }
    fun proximo(view: View) {
        if (x < imgs.size-1) {
            x += 1
            img01.setImageResource(imgs[x])
        }
    }
...
}
```